# Logstash Persistent Queues Not Creating Tail Files

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-5

I have just started playing with logstash 5.4.0 persistent queues.
I have configured logstash to use persistent queues though this always writes to head and never rolls the head over to tail.

My logstash.yml is as follows

```
queue.checkpoint.writes: 1   
queue.type: persisted
path.queue: /usr/share/logstash/persisted-queues
queue.page_capacity: 1000mb
```

And creates

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1048576000 Feb 23 14:14 page.1
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34 Feb 23 14:14 checkpoint.head

a few minute later I get

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1048576000 Feb 23 14:15 page.1
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34 Feb 23 14:14 checkpoint.head

The size of the file remains consistent and when I cat the page file I can see it changing.

Comment: Hey! Did you ever figure out why the tails pages aren't being created? I'm running into this same issue. Thanks!